# Iframe isn't displayed in IE on some URLs

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have simple html code:

```
<iframe src="http://public.bullhornstaffing.com" width="500" height="700"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://public.bullhornstaffing.com/JobBoard/Standard/default.cfm?privateLabelID=9076" width="500" height="700"></iframe>
```

The first iframe displayed excellent in all browsers, but second iframe isn't displayed in IE instead of the page I see the text "Site Not Found. The site your are trying to find does not exist."
But when I try to open iframe url in the browser directly - everything works as it is necessary.

There is method to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The URL of the second `iframe` gets redirected to http://public.bullhornstaffing.com/JobBoard/Standard/BHContent_JobOpportunities.cfm and for some reason, the server responds to it differently when accessed on IE via `iframe` (or otherwise as embedded). What you get is technically a normal server response, just with special content.

It is at the discretion of server admin to do such things, e.g. in an attempt at preventing framing, though this behavior might be unintentional. Contact the server admin.